# "Inside" or "inside of"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've been reading this text:

> When you define a type, you can define static data fields within it.
>   The bytes that back these static data fields are allocated within the
>   type objects themselves. **Finally, inside each type object is a
>   method table with one entry per method defined within the type.** This
>   is the method table that was discussed in Chapter 1.
>
> Richter, Jeffrey (2010-02-05). CLR via C# (Kindle Locations
>   3546-3548). OReilly Media - A. Kindle Edition.

However, the bolded text made me confused. Should it be *inside of* instead of *inside*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, *[inside](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inside#Preposition)* as a preposition meaning "within the interior of something" is correct here. The phrase *the inside of X* uses *[inside](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inside#Noun)* as a noun, meaning "interior or inner part".  "Inside of each type object is a method table" has minor grammar problems such as no article for *inside*.  One could pedantically, properly, and verbosely say "The inside of each type object contains a method table", but just saying "Inside each type object is a method table" is both correct and direct.

Comment: Isn't inside in "inside of something" means the same thing as "interior or inner part" ?

Comment: +1: Here is an [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Inside+the%2CInside+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) showing that when it starts a sentence (note the capital letter), "Inside the ..." is much more common than "Inside of the". Here, we know that *inside* is a preposition because it starts a sentence. If *inside* were a noun, it would be "The inside of the ...", and you would need to use *of*. However, I believe (and Ngrams confirms) that *inside of* is occasionally used as a preposition in American English, where it is synonymous with *inside*.

Comment: Note, above comments were written while I was overhauling my answer, but I think they still apply. @Peter, I also added a *the* in "the phrase *the inside of X* uses inside as a noun" for the latter reason you mention, *inside of* occasionally being prepositiony.

Comment: I am pretty sure that *inside of* can be a preposition [in the U.S.,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=him+inside+the%2Chim+inside+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) but I don't believe you can use *inside of* as a preposition [in the U.K.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=him+inside+the%2Chim+inside+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) Looking at the Google hits for "him inside of the", they seem to be virtually all American. And even in American English, *inside* is much more common as a preposition than *inside of*.

Answer (score 3):

As @jwpat7 says, *inside* is normally used as a "standalone" preposition. But I don't think there's anything inherently "ungrammatical" about using *inside **of*** in this way, and it was certainly [far from unknown](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=placed%20inside%20the,placed%20inside%20of%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) a century ago...

[image]

Today though, unless the context is a noun usage *(**the inside of** something)*, omit the *"of"*.

Comment: Compare the [British](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=placed+inside+the%2Cplaced+inside+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) and [American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=placed+inside+the%2Cplaced+inside+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) Ngrams for "placed inside of the". I'd say "inside of" is still O.K. informally as a preposition in the U.S. today (although it's dying out), but I'm not sure it has ever been acceptable in the U.K.

Comment: @Peter Shor: That agrees with your comment to jwpat7's answer, saying prepositional *inside of* is primarily American. As a Brit I have to say I don't find it *that* objectionable, even though it's non-standard. My reason for posting was simply to make the point that this isn't really a 100% right/wrong issue - it's really a matter of idiomatic choice regarding the prepositional usage which as you say (said?!) didn't even exist until a couple of hundred years ago.