# "Inside her" or "inside of her"

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbials

> Lit a fire "inside her" or "inside of her"

1. Which is correct in this case?
2. Is "inside" a preposition here?

I read the similar questions to mine, in particular this one - [“Inside of a house” versus “inside a house”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119971/inside-of-a-house-versus-inside-a-house)?

I'm pretty sure the correct answer to my question is "inside of her," because inside is a noun (a place) But because my scenario is talking about a person instead of an object I'm still a bit unsure

Comment: Hello Jessie! Please, please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), taking care to note the comments on search & research, including: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: I read the similar questions to mine, in particular this one- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119971/inside-of-a-house-versus-inside-a-house
I'm pretty sure the correct answer to my question is inside of her, because inside is a noun (a place)
But because my scenario is talking about a person instead of an object I'm still a bit unsure

Comment: The expression is metaphoric so the preposition is not one which expresses a purely physical juxtaposition. I would say that 'lit a fire within her' is more idiomatic. The fire is within her person, not inside her abdominal structures. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: @Jessie Thanks. I've added your comments, including your indicated research, to your question. Now it's a better question.

Comment: Neither. You light a fire under someone, or under an animal to get it moving again. I think it comes from an Arab idiom with possibly a literal reference to lighting a fire under a camel to get it moving (or else you die).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Inside" or "inside of"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64504/inside-or-inside-of)

Comment: Why not: X lit a fire in or within her.  Agree with Nigel but just in works fine, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The use of preposition "of"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206004/the-use-of-preposition-of)

Comment: “Outside of a Dog, a Book is Man’s Best Friend. Inside of a Dog, It’s Too Dark to Read.” – [attributed to Groucho Marx, Jim Brewer, Mary Stuart, or possibly somebody else](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2010/09/08/dog/).  Although [the Orlando Sentinel claims](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/1993-09-15/news/9309150125_1_volcanoes-treat-your-cat-golf-ball) that what Groucho Marx actually said was: “Outside a dog, a book is man’s best friend. Inside a dog, it’s too dark to read.” (without ***of***)

Comment: Neither is correct.  You can't light a fire inside someone -- there's no oxygen.  (Now, if you intend the phrase to be figurative then you've got to acknowledge that there's no single way to describe an imaginary action.)

Answer (score 2):

To be safe, you might want to use *inside her*, because that seems more acceptable to English speakers as a whole.

In your clause *lit a fire inside (of) her*, either *inside* or *inside of* are used. In the first case *inside* is a preposition; in the second case *inside of* is a two-word preposition.

Note that [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/inside_1) says *inside of* is "sometimes used instead of *inside*, especially in American English."

Nevertheless, Americans also say *inside*. In either case, *inside her* and *inside of her* are used. Also: *I lit a fire inside the fireplace* versus *I lit a fire inside of the fireplace*. Either is fine, at least to many speakers of American English, although presumably speakers of British speakers would prefer the version without *of*.

Compare the well-worn phrase *think outside (of) the box*.

There are hundreds of google hits for both [think outside the box](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&q=%22think+outside+the+box%22&oq=%22think+outside+the+box%22&aq=f&aqi=d1d-o1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1747l10657l0l12519l53l52l1l38l0l2l544l2599l3.7.1.5-2l13l0) and [think outside of the box](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&gl=us&tbm=nws&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22think+outside+of+the+box%22&pbx=1&oq=%22think+outside+of+the+box%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=12079l12319l0l13461l3l3l0l0l0l1l139l289l2.1l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=987&bih=685&cad=h) and the version with *of* has been used in such reputable journals as *Forbes* and many other periodicals.

*Inside* is not a noun in either version of your clause, because you can't place an article before it. Both the following are not grammatical:

*Lit a fire the inside her.
*Lit a fire the inside of her.

See also [tchrist's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/424406/210913) to [Is the word 'outside' a preposition or a noun in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424350/is-the-word-outside-a-preposition-or-a-noun-in-this-context) (you can start reading with the sentence that begins *Here's an example that uses outside as five different parts of speech*, which is followed by the highlighted box showing five uses of *outside*; the same uses apply to *inside*.)

Answer (score -1):

The phrase, “inside of,” is redundant in my opinion. If you just use the preposition “inside,” you have already established where the object in question is. Therefore why would you want to add yet another preposition, in this case the word “of”? It’s just like saying, “That’s a round circle.”

Answer (score -1):

There was a young lady, a bride, / 
Who ate some green apples and died. / 
The apples fermented / 
Inside the lamented, /
Making cider inside her inside.

Answer (score -4):

Which is correct depends upon the language of the context...
In English, "inside her" is correct,
In American, "inside of her" is usual. 
(The Americans seem to like putting an "of" in all sorts of places that the Brits don't.)

Comment: There is no such language as "American".

Comment: Both usages apply to both. And I agree with tchrist, American is not a language.